# Cuando pongo esta variable mi boton en android studio se bloquea

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-sqlite

Estoy ocupando un campo llamado actualizar donde tengo que deshabilitar y habilitar un mismo boton pero al momento de deshabilitarlo(else) ya no me deja volver a habilitarlo se me bloquea el boton(ya no me genera lo del if). Estoy ocupando if y else para hacerlo con el atributo button.setenabled(); con su respectivo true y false

```
 public void actualizar(){

    try {

        if(!matricula.getText().toString().equals("")&&!descrip.getText().toString().equals("")) {
            actualizar.setEnabled(true);
            db.execSQL("UPDATE medicamentos set medicamento='" + matricula.getText().toString() + "' 
        ,formula='" + modelo.getText().toString()+"' ,descripcion='" + descrip.getText().toString() + 
  "' WHERE 
 id='" + aux + "'");
            Toast.makeText(this, "Actualizado con exito", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }else {

           actualizar.setEnabled(false);

            //Toast.makeText(this, "Por favor llene todos los campos", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

    }catch (Exception e){
        //Toast.makeText(this,"ERROR\n"+ e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: cuando llene los campos , habilitas el boton.

Answer (score 0):

Es normal porque probablemente el método actualizar() se ejecuta al pulsar el botón actualizar, por lo que en tu código lo deshabilitas y no hay ningún mecanismo que lo habilite.  Una opción es que uses TextWatcher con tus EditText, concretamente el método onTextChanged() y ahí habilitar y deshabilitar el botón actualizar:

```
matricula.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
      Boolean hasText = !matricula.getText().toString().equals("")
      actualizar.setEnabled(hasText);  
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        // Do nothing
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        // Do nothing
    }
});


descrip.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
      Boolean hasText = !matricula.getText().toString().equals("")
      actualizar.setEnabled(hasText);  
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        // Do nothing
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        // Do nothing
    }
});
```

Para poner el código más bonito puedes crear una clase TextWatcherImpl que implemente la interfaz TextWatcher:

```
class TextWatcherImpl implements TextWatcher {
    
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
        
    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

    }
}
```

Y en tu clase ahora el código se simplifica:

```
matricula.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcherImpl() {
 @Override
 public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
   super.onTextChanged(charSequence, i, i1, i2);
   Boolean hasText = !matricula.getText().toString().equals("")
   actualizar.setEnabled(hasText);  
  }
});
```

Y por último, como esta lógica para activar o desactivar el botón de Actualizar se repite dos veces, se puede extraer en un método que reciba el EditText por parámetro y así poder reutilizarlo:

```
void handleUpdateButtonState(EditText editText) {
        editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcherImpl() {
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                super.onTextChanged(charSequence, i, i1, i2);
                Boolean hasText = !editText.getText().toString().equals("")
                actualizar.setEnabled(hasText);
            }
        });
    }
```